# UIPageController currentPage stubbornly sets itself to nib value

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xib, uipagecontrol

I have a `UIPageController` that I placed in my xib file, so I could get the placement proper, but the value of "currentPage" set in the xib is the value that currentPage assumes when i try to set it to something else, like below, the line of code that sets my `UIScrollView` to the proper initial image when starting in the middle (i.e. not page 0):

```
aScrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake((currentIndex + 0.0) * screenWidth, 0.0);
```

which calls

```
-(void) scrollViewDidScroll: (UIScrollView*) aScrollView
{
    // Update the page control to match the current scroll:
    CGPoint offset = aScrollView.contentOffset;
    float width = self.view.frame.size.width;
    int pageNumber = (int)(offset.x / width);
    uiPageControl.currentPage = pageNumber;
    NSLog(@"%g // %g = %d", offset.x, width, (int)(offset.x/width));

}
```

The pageNumber integer is correct, so I am properly calculating the desired page number from the offset.  However, when I try to manually (programatically) set currentPage, it doesn't set to pageNumber, it sets to the value in the xib.

Easy solution is to not use the xib and do it all programatically, but I want to know how I can continue using the `UIPageController` in the xib, because it was easy to place without knowledge of coordinates, etc.  Normally, Attributes set in the xib are overwritable programatically, so this bug really surprised me. Any suggestions on how I can properly set currentPage?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I found a hack that temporarily solves my problem: in the xib, I set the "Number of Pages" value to something I know will be higher than the number of pages I will ever have.

If this is too small, it turns out that setting currentPage beyond that value didn't do anything because it was clamping or setting it to some number below the number of pages I had in the xib.

If I set this xib attribute higher, then setting currentPage works.

Sorry for the quick trigger.